# visual studio 2010 unable to start program .dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll

I have a problem for my visual studio 2010. When I click start debugging button and it's start debugging.

It seems that there is no error "i just create one "button" on it "

But it will show `Unable to start program 'c:\users\.....\xx.dll'`

Does someone now how to solve it?

The second question is: when I click left button to see the "Button" source code,
why it will show all this project code? Should I revise some setting?

Answer (score 27):

Visual studio will not run a .dll by itself. does your solution have an .exe project? if so, right click it and select "Set as Startup Project". if not you will need to create one, and instruct it to load the forms within your dll.

as for left clicking the button, I'm not quite sure what you are describing. can you post a picture?

Comment: Same problem happened to me. I had two sub-projects in my solution: one is a DLL project and the other is an EXE project (which uses the DLL project). Only when I set the EXE project to be the start-up project I could debug the program. I now understand that VS2010 was trying to run the DLL as the main program and hence the error message it gave.

Comment: Perfect (Y) post and comment, thank you both so much

Answer (score 8):

In earlier versions of MSVC while running .dll, will get a dialog asking path for .exe file

But in MSVC 2010 and above there is no such option. To fix this

> 1. Right click on your dll project
> 2. Properties
> 3. Configuration Properties > Debugging. Here, in Command -> add path to your exe.

Add command arguments, if any.

You are good to go!